# How to extend Git (Windows) with scripts that inherit shell variables?

Tags: bash, git, shell, perl

I'm a developer running Git for Windows v2.12.2(2) and using the GitBash program that comes with it for all my shell needs. The version of `bash` available in this shell appears to be v4.4.12(1). I'm on Windows 10.

I've got a Perl script I wish for Git to pickup and execute when I run the command `git my-script`. I've ensured the script is on my `PATH`, and I'm able to run `git my-script` and see that my script is running. But, my script requires custom modules located at a couple places on my filesystem, and which it cannot find when run via `git my-script`. I know I have all my shell variables configured correctly; if I run the script directly (i.e. `perl /path/to/git-my-script`), it works without an issue.

For the purposes of this question, take this very simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Print all directories searched for perl modules
print "$_\n" for @INC;
```

When run via `perl /path/to/my-script`, it outputs all directories as expected. When run via `git my-script`, it outputs the same directories *except* for the ones defined in my `PERL5LIB` variable (which are the ones needed).

What shell is `git my-script` invoking that doesn't inherit my PERL5LIB variable? Is this a windows-specific problem? Is there some other config file I need to adjust, or some system variable I must define?

**EDIT**: I suspect `git` invokes `/bin/sh`, which keeps complaining about `__git_ps1` not being a defined function. When I define it as `__git_ps1 () { return; }`, the `PERL5LIB` variable suddenly becomes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What shell is `git my-script` invoking that doesn't inherit my `PERL5LIB` variable?

Because Git has its own Perl.

That is made more explicit in Git 2.20 (Q4 2018):

See [commit 0e218f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e218f91c299b0bffa281d3449884a824819a201), [commit bdfbb0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdfbb0ea932d1ec479474cc7928ec9d47ea89e7b), [commit 70fc579](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70fc5793dfdf8ba8586ca130674f6896eb3eb37a), [commit 409670f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/409670f34ed5a2bc4f508f3aee9f809922b339dc) (30 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c268fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c268fdda9dcc421e2bee1ce76496d3e9f96397f), 13 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: unset `PERL5LIB` by default
>
> Git for Windows ships with its own Perl interpreter, and insists on using it, so it will most likely wreak havoc if `PERL5LIB` is set before launching Git.
>
> Let's just unset that environment variables when spawning processes.
>
> To make this feature extensible (and overrideable), there is a new config setting `core.unsetenvvars` that allows specifying a comma-separated list of names to unset before spawning processes.
>
> Reported by Gabriel Fuhrmann.

In your case, you will be able to set `core.unsetenvvar` to "empty" in order to *not* unset `PERL5LIB`, but you will also have to adjust `PERL5LIB` to [`GITPERLLIB`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c/wrap-for-bin.sh#L17) plus your own folders.